# Unable to run tomcat on XAMPP(windows)

Tags: java, windows, xampp

I am using the windows 10 64 bit operating system.

When I open the xampp control panel and click on the start button. It says "**Attempting to start tomcat**" but then it gives no response

[image]

Then I went through some online solutions given

**solution 1**
Add the JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME paths in environment variables
[image]

**solution 2**
changed the key name to

```
HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK
```

in **tomcat_service_install.bat** and **tomcat_service_uninstall.bat**

Even after trying these solutions, Tomcat is not working. Can someone help me with this problem?

If I missed out on any important information, I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the log file. The default port number 8005 and 8080 may be used by some other applications.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But there is a little cross (red) just to the left of the tomcat. When I click that it says **Service was not un(installed)**. Is there anything I can do to resolve this as well?

Comment: Just run the Xampp Control Panel. Then open Config and Enable Tomcat from Auto-start option.